# Get macro triggered every time a Microsoft form is submitted

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-forms

I have made a form with Microsoft Forms and in the same Excel file, I have a macro which triggers every time there is a change in eg. A2-A20.

So my goal is to get the macro triggered every time someone submit and the data comes in.
But it seems like that the macro won't get triggered, when someone submit the form and the data gets added to the Excel file.
The macro works fine when I write something in one of the cells myself.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    
    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A2:A20")
 
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        
        'Get name for new workbook
        Dim WBnew As Variant
        WBnew = Range("E" & Target.Row).Value
        
        ' Creates a reference to workbook object
        Dim WB As Workbook
 
        'Adding a New Workbook
        Set WB = Workbooks.Add
    
        'Set where to save the Workbook and name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & WBnew & ".xls"
 
         'Copy entire row
        Workbooks("Test forms.xlsm").Worksheets("Form1").Range(Target.Row & ":" & Target.Row).Copy
 
        'Paste to row 2 in the new workbook
        Workbooks(WBnew & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1").Insert
        
        'Copy row 1 in old workbook and paste it to the new workbooks row 1
        Workbooks("Test forms.xlsm").Worksheets("Form1").Range("1:1").Copy
        Workbooks(WBnew & ".xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1").Insert

        'Save the workbook
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
 
End If
 
End Sub
```

Any idea what to do, so the macro will get triggered, when new data comes in from the form?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What "works fine when I write in the cell myself"? Should we deduce what problem you have? Then, do you use `Worksheet_Change` event and you need to also trigger the changes produced in cells by formulas update? If yes, you should use `Worksheet_Calculate` event. If this is not your problem, edit your question and share the code you use, please.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have updated my question with some code also.

Comment: The `Change` event is triggered only when cell contents is changed. It's not clear exactly what you want to trigger the code.

Comment: Are there formulas in the range you are talking about and you want the event to be triggered when these cells value is changed by modification in other sheets?

Comment: @SJR I just what the code to get triggered when the content is changed in one of the cells. When someone submit a form the answers will automatically get added to the sheet on a new row, which should trigger the code (but don't). If I just write something in the cell manually, it will get triggered.

Comment: @FaneDuru There are no formulas. 
I want the event to be triggered when new data comes in from the Microsoft Form, which happens automatically. There is no other sheets.

Comment: Can you explain what does "someone submit a form" mean? If the cells are changed manually or by code, the event will be triggered. But you are talking about "added to the sheet on a new row" and your code deals with a fix range ("A2:A20"). Is it possible that this "new row" to exceed the range as it has been defined?

Comment: Do you mean a userform in Excel or something else?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, like when a person fills out a survey and submit it. The things they have answered will automatically get transferred to the Excel file.

Comment: You answered only half or my question... Is it possible that the new inserted row to exceed "A20"? Anyhow, you must make our range dinamic. I mean, the code to calculate the last row in col A:A.

Comment: @SJR No it's Microsoft Forms. This video explains it pretty well https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-results-in-microsoft-forms-31c4b0cd-a89b-42e7-9429-1c14a1d8ef67

Comment: @FaneDuru Sorry I didn't see the other half. Right now there is only 2 rows so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Does this application work on your computer or online? I mean, in browser... I do not know it. It maybe can be set to trigger or not the Excel workbook events.

Comment: @FaneDuru That could actually be the problem. The Microsoft Form can only be created in the browser, but I believe macros doesn't work in the browser. Or am I wrong here?